# convert a column into a header and fetch corresponding values

Tags: excel

i need a way to convert table a to table b as shown in the image:

[image: i need a way to convert table a to table b as shown in the image]
I dont how to communicate this verbally so i have given a picture of my problem, I need to convert table a to table b in excel. Can anyone help?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: try adding column headers (you can even hide them later) and create a pivot table